# What does ~ after the file extension mean?

Tags: php, file, filenames

I am hoping this will be an easy item for some of you to answer. I am looking at some PHP files and I am seeing stuff where there will be one file:

> file1.php

and then there will be a second file called:

> file1.php~

I have never seen this before so I am wondering what the tilde (~) after the extension means...

Comment: What application do you use to create/edit your PHP files?

Comment: That is just a temporary / backup file that some programs create when you're editing; it should clean itself up automatically. You can ignore or delete them.

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/173151/what-does-the-tilde-at-the-end-of-a-file-name-stand-for

Comment: First I use sublime text to create and edit files - but I did not create these files - I am looking at someone else's stuff.  Second, thanks M Martin for your help in understanding this...

Comment: These types of files are usually created when a text editor crashes, or if editing via SSH and nano/pico, the connection drops. Usually they can just be deleted.

Comment: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/76189/what-does-the-tilde-mean-at-the-end-of-a-filename and http://askubuntu.com/questions/173151/what-does-the-tilde-at-the-end-of-a-file-name-stand-for

Answer (score 0):

Well it simply is a back up file created by the editor you are using. You can avoid them by changing the settings in the editor. These can be irritating at times while selecting the file to work on but in case if you accidentally delete any of your working file then you can use this backup file.